# Granting access to specific directory in an SVN repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository

I want to grant a user access to only specific directory (including its sub-directories) in my SVN repository and not the whole repository, is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you're using the http access method. See the svn book: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.perdir

Answer (score 4):

If you're using either apache or svnserve you can set [path based access control](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html)

With apache you set `AuthzSVNAccessFile` to point to a file that lists the access rules you wish to apply, your apache config ends up looking like:

```
<Location /repos>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /mnt/storage/svn

  AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/svn-accessfile

  Require valid-user  
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/users.conf
</Location>
```

Typically these end up looking something like:

```
[calc:/branches/calc/bug-142]
harry = rw
sally = r
```

Comment: What about `externals`? If the target path takes some other source folders via `externals`, will we need separate permissions for those external folders too?

Comment: @Danijel - externals are separate repositories, with their own Authentication and access controls. You'll need to set things up with them too, there's no magic way of making it transfer across.

Comment: In this line: "calc:/branches/calc/bug-142", /branches start from system (/) path? Thanks.

Comment: @fck it's not a file path, it's a repository path where / is the top of the repository.

Answer (score 1):

I use USVN but there are many other web interfaces that work with apache to provide SVN authentication protocols and repositories/directory permissions.

I know that USVN allows fine grained directory based permissions on the READ and WRITE and use MySQL as an account provider for authentication.